# Grab all IDs except for Min Value

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the other `KeyLocationIDs` from the `NumberOfDuplicates`. I want to exclude the `Min(KeyLocationID)` and want a list of the others.

```
select CompanyID, Location, EventCode, count(*) as NumberOfDuplicates, min(KeyLocationID) as KeepThisOne
from trip.KeyLocations
group by CompanyID, Location, EventCode
having count (*) > 1
order by location asc
```

Comment: include `WHERE KeyLocationID > min(KeyLocationID)` before `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing here is the where statment.
There are several ways to do this, here are some examples:
as sugested by @nobody
or you could do:

```
select CompanyID, Location, EventCode, count(*) as NumberOfDuplicates, 
min(KeyLocationID) as KeepThisOne
from trip.KeyLocations
group by CompanyID, Location, EventCode
having KeyLocationID > min(KeyLocationID)
order by location asc
```

OR you could do:

```
select CompanyID, Location, EventCode, count(*) as NumberOfDuplicates, 
min(KeyLocationID) as KeepThisOne
from trip.KeyLocations
group by CompanyID, Location, EventCode
having KeyLocationID != MIN(KeyLocationID)
order by location asc
```

Comment: Unfortunately both of these return: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Do you have an example, I am not familiar with what you mean

Answer (score 0):

select CompanyID, Location, EventCode, count(*) as NumberOfDuplicates
from trip.KeyLocations
where 
KeyLocationID not in (select min(KeyLocationID) from trip.KeyLocations group by CompanyID, Location, EventCode)
group by CompanyID, Location, EventCode
having count (*) > 1
order by location asc